# How to read every line after :

Tags: java, file, io

I have a TXT file like this:

```
Start: Here is a random introduction.

Items:
Item 1
Item 2
Item 3
Item 4

End: Here is a random outro.
```

I want to retrieve Item 1, Item 2, Item 3, Item 4 and put them into a data structure like a HashMap. How can I achieve this?

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = null;

        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            String line = scanner.nextLine();

            if (line.startsWith("Start:")) {
                String time = line.substring(6);
            }

            if (line.matches("Items:") && scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String items = line;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: show example of lines in file

Comment: @user7294900
Items:

 - Item 1
 - Item 2
 - Item 3

Comment: What is the problem with your code?

Comment: @Jens I don't know how to only "save" certain lines of a file. For example here I only want to have Item 1, Item 2, Item 3 and Item 4 and the rest of the lines I don't need.

Answer (score 0):

[Updated Answer] So the other answer on this question is helpful if the exact words are know that are to be ignored but when there is a big file with lot of lines than this solution will be more accurate.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     String line = "";
     String[] parts = null;
     HashMap<String, String> hashmap=new HashMap<String, String>();

     try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Zoo.txt"));
            //line = br.readLine();

            while (line != null) {
            line = br.readLine();
           //System.out.println(line.toString());
          if(line!=null){
                //System.out.println(line);

              if(line.contains("Item")&& line.substring(0, 5).compareTo("Item ")==0){        
                    addToHashMap(line,hashmap);
                    System.out.println(line);

              }
          }     
}
            br.close();
            }catch(IOException ioe){
                System.err.println(ioe.getMessage());

}

}

private static  void addToHashMap(String line, HashMap<String,String> hashMap) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Random random=new Random();
    hashMap.put(Integer.toString(random.nextInt(100)), line);       

     }
```

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to mention that I need only certain parts of this text file. Here is a textfile example, where I would only need the lines: Item 1, Item 2, Item 3:  

Here is a random introduction.  

Items:  
Item 1 
Item 2 . 
Item 3 . 
Item 4 . 
 
Here is a random outro.

Comment: Now only line having word "Item" will get selected.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(TestCdllLogger.class.getResourceAsStream("/test.txt"));

    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        String line = scanner.nextLine();

        if (line.startsWith("Start:") || line.startsWith("End:") || line.startsWith("Items:") || line.startsWith(" ") ||line.isEmpty() ) {
            continue;
        }

        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```

it ignores all lines starts with `Start:`, `End:`, `Items:` and blank or emty lines.

I know that the code write the lines to stdout and not to a file, but this can changed by your own